# How can I code the sequence of [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,5] in 2.5 or 3 bits?

Tags: machine-learning, entropy, information-theory

If I calculate the entropy for the following sequence:
[1,2,3,4,5,6,6,5]

I get the entropy of 2.5 but I am wondering how can I actually do the encoding with 2.5 or 3 bits. Does it mean I need 3 bits like the following:

1 - 000

2 - 001

3 - 010

4 - 011

5 - 100

6 - 101

Does the entropy value mean I need 2.5 bits to encode the whole sequence? Hope to hear some explanations.

Comment: In order to construct an efficient code, you need the probability distribution of the source symbols, which are 1,2,3,4,5, and 6 in this case. Can you include the probability distribution that you used to compute the entropy in the question?

Comment: I just used each freqeuncy of the numbers in the sequence to calculate the entropy value. There are eight numbers and each number has a probability of 1/8 except the number 5 and 6 which have 2/8. Which probability distribution can I say I used if I just used the frequencies of the numbers?

Comment: You list two fives, two sixes, and no eights: is that intentional?  For an answer to your apparent question, search this site (and the Web) for "prefix code."  The standard algorithm for an optimal prefix code produces one like 000, 001, 010, 011, 10, 11 for the digits 1 through 6, respectively--and you can readily verify this uses 2.5 bits on average.

Comment: I just fixed it. I didn't notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, the probability distribution of the source symbols $1,2,3,4,5,$ and $6$ is:

$$
p(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{8}, & x = 1,2,3,4 \\
\frac{2}{8}, & x = 5,6
\end{cases}
$$

Two types of source codes that you can construct are fixed-length source codes and variable-length source codes. The one that you listed in your question is an example of a fixed-length source code. An advantage of fixed-length source codes is that they will always be uniquely decodable. In other words, if you concatenate any combination of the codewords together, you will always be able to decode them back into source symbols. In the case of fixed-length source codes, you can do this since you already know that all codewords will be of the same length. However, they are generally less efficient than variable-length codes in terms of the average length of the codewords.

For variable-length source codes, it is important that each codeword in the code is uniquely decodable. One way to ensure that this happens is by constructing a [prefix code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code). An optimal way of constructing a prefix code, in the sense that it minimizes the average codeword length, is by constructing a [Huffman code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding).

As @whuber mentioned in their comment, one possible Huffman code is:

$$
1 \rightarrow 000 \\
2 \rightarrow 001 \\
3 \rightarrow 010 \\
4 \rightarrow 011 \\
5 \rightarrow 10 \\
6 \rightarrow 11
$$

Notice that no codeword is a prefix of any other codeword. Hence, this is a prefix code and it is uniquely decodable. Also, this code achieves an average codeword length (aka rate of compression) of $2.5$ bits per source symbol, which is the lowest possible average codeword length.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So 2.5 bits means that I cannot get any less than 2.5 bits to encode a letter in the sequence and therefore the entropy value means the lowest number of bits I can encode each letter the sequence?

Comment: You can never achieve an **average** codeword length for a **lossless** code less than the entropy of any set of source symbols. This is known as [Shannon's source coding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%27s_source_coding_theorem).